# java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, excepciones

estoy teniendo un problema con la lectura/escritura de objetos en java mediante ObjectInputStream.
El caso es el siguiente, quiero almacenar en un archivo una serie de objetos de diferente tipo (diferentes clases que heredan de la misma). Pero la cuestión es que quiero en primer lugar crear el archivo y añadir unos objetos, y a continuacion mediante otro metodo seguir escribiendo sobre el mismo archivo.

Por lo tanto he creado el siguiente main que intenta hacer esto, pero no se porque razón me salta la excepción **java.lang.ClassCastException** en la linea 24, al parecer es un problema con el casteo de aquellos objetos que he añadido con el método "segundaEscritura()" al archivo, pero por mas vueltas que doy no saco la solucion.

Resumiendo, el main principal del programa seria el siguiente.

```
public class Main2 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    PrimeraEscritura();
    SegundaEscritura();
    //Lectura
    try(ObjectInputStream fe=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\prueba\\hola.dat"))){
        Revistas revistaLeida=null;
        Libros libroLeido=null;

        Object lector=fe.readObject();

        while(lector!=null) {
            if (lector instanceof Libros) {
                libroLeido= (Libros) lector;
                System.out.println(libroLeido.toString());
            }else {
                revistaLeida= (Revistas) lector;
                System.out.println(revistaLeida.toString());
            }
            lector=fe.readObject();
        };

        System.out.println("Lectura finalizada");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static void PrimeraEscritura() {
        //Primera escritura

        Libros libro=new Libros("B","BB",new GregorianCalendar(1999,3,12),"A","A");
        Libros libro2=new Libros("B","BB",new GregorianCalendar(1999,3,12),"B","B");
        Revistas revista=new Revistas("A","AA",new GregorianCalendar(1999,3,12),1,22);
        try(ObjectOutputStream fs = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\prueba\\hola.dat"))) {

            fs.writeObject((Object) libro);
            fs.writeObject((Object) libro2);
            fs.writeObject((Object) revista);
        fs.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ef) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: ARCHIVO NO ENCONTRADO");
            ef.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR DE ESCRITURA");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


public static void SegundaEscritura() {
        //Segunda escritura
        Revistas revista2=new Revistas("A","AA",new GregorianCalendar(1999,3,12),2,22);

        try(MiObjectOutputStream mifs = new MiObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\prueba\\hola.dat",true))) {
            mifs.writeObject((Object) revista2);
            mifs.close();           
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ef) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: ARCHIVO NO ENCONTRADO");
            ef.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR DE ESCRITURA");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

El flujo de salida **MiObjectOutputStream** que estoy empleando para la segunda escritura es una clase modificada para que no añada la cabecera de nuevo al fichero, esta seria la clase

```
public class MiObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

/** Constructor que recibe OutputStream */
public MiObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException{
    super(out);
}

/** Constructor sin parámetros */
protected MiObjectOutputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException{
    super();
}

/** Redefinición del método de escribir la cabecera para que no haga nada. */
protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException{
}
```

Añado también la traza de la excepción

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readTypeString(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at EjercicioObject.Main2.main(Main2.java:24)
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a una respuesta en la version en [ingles del sitio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607969/appending-objects-to-a-serialization-file):

En lugar de no hacer nada en `writeStreamHeader()`, invoca a `reset()`:

```
/**
 * Redefinición del método de escribir la cabecera para que no haga
 * nada.
 */
@Override
protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
    reset();
}
```

Ademas, al leer objetos desde el stream debes tomar en cuenta que alcanzar el final del archivo no es un error:

```
while (lector != null) {
    if (lector instanceof Libros) {
        libroLeido = (Libros) lector;
        System.out.println(libroLeido.toString());
    } else {
        revistaLeida = (Revistas) lector;
        System.out.println(revistaLeida.toString());
    }
    try {
        lector = fe.readObject();
    } catch (EOFException eof) {
        lector = null;
    }
}
```